# array_key_exist() with array as key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if in an array there is any value of another array. The function `array_key_exist()` looks like what I'm searching for, but I don't understand how to give the key value at the function as an array. Here's the code:

```
$risultato_query_controllo_numero = mysql_query($query_controllo_numero);
$voucher_esistenti = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato_query_controllo_numero))) {
    $voucher_esistenti[] = $row['numero'];
}
```

Which populates the first array with numbers:

```
$voucher = range($numero, $numero + $quantita);
```

Which populates the second array with numbers.

What I need to do now is to check if any of the value in `$voucher` is present in `$voucher_presenti`.

Comment: The function you are looking for is [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Both your arrays are indexed with sequential numbers starting from 0, their keys are not interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `array_intersect` function:

```
$overlap = array_intersect($voucher, $voucher_presenti);
```

You can find more examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Comment: Didn't know that function. Nice and clean answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `in_array()` function to get the result you are looking for.

```
$arrayOne = range(1, 10);
$arrayTwo = range(5, 15);
foreach ($arrayOne as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $arrayTwo)) {
        echo 'value '.$value.' is in the first and second array.<br />';
    }
}
```

#### Resources

- [in_array() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

in_array could be a good solution for your need, for example you can assign $voucher_esistenti only when you have a new value in the sql row.

```
$risultato_query_controllo_numero=mysql_query($query_controllo_numero);
$voucher_esistenti=array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato_query_controllo_numero))){
    if(!in_array($row['numero'], $voucher_esistenti) {
         $voucher_esistenti[] = $row['numero'];
    }
} // this solution isn't optimal, because you will check subarrays with each new value
```

There's a better way to achieve that, by using a hashmap which has a complexity of O(1) ( best complexity :) )

```
$risultato_query_controllo_numero=mysql_query($query_controllo_numero);
$voucher_esistenti=array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato_query_controllo_numero))){
// here is what we changed, instead of key = value, we actually append keys
    if(!isset($voucher_esistenti[$row['numero']]) {
        $voucher_esistenti[$row['numero']] = true;
    }
} 
/*
The second implementation is a lot faster due to the algorithm, but you will have to change the reading of $voucher_esistenti array. */
```